# i am not getting error missing keyword in my code

Tags: sql, database, oracle, data-analysis

```
select e.department_id,e.salary,d.department_name 
from employees e
join departments d
    on d.department_id=e.department_id
inner join
    (
        select department_id,max(salary) as max_sal from employees
        group by department_id
    ) as t
    on e.department_id=t.department_id
where e.salary =t.max_sal;
```

Comment: what are you asking?

Comment: I cannot see any reason that you should get a "missing keyword" error here.  Why do you think that you should?

Comment: Welcome on SO. The only potential error is the use of as keyword before t table name. Some DBMS don't want it, but please highlight your error, so we can help you.

Comment: exactly,but its giving error :ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword" at subquery aliasing section )as t

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please ask questions clearly. Try to review it a couple of times before posting it. Try to give as many details as you can. Also share what you have done so far to resolve this issue. This will make your and other users' experience better. :)

Answer (score 3):

Oracle does not support `as` for table aliases, so you can try:

```
select e.department_id, e.salary, d.department_name 
from employees e join
     departments d
     on d.department_id = e.department_id inner join
     (select department_id, max(salary) as max_sal
      from employees
      group by department_id
     ) t
     on e.department_id = t.department_id
where e.salary = t.max_sal;
```

Of course, this would be better written using window functions, but this answers the question that you asked.